# Similar references to themselves in two classes

Tags: c#, refactoring, generics

How can I make 1 class (base, generic or something else) from these two classes?

```
class A
{
  A Link { get; set; }
}

class B
{
  B Link { get; set; }
}
```

**UPD:** This is what I have now:

```
class BSTree
{
  public BSTNode Root { get; set; }
}

class AVLTree
{
  public AVLNode Root { get; set; }
}

class BSTNode
{
  public BSTNode Parent { get; set; }
  public BSTNode Left { get; set; }
  public BSTNode Right{ get; set; }
  public int Key{ get; set; }
}

class AVLNode
{
  public AVLNode Parent { get; set; }
  public AVLNode Left { get; set; }
  public AVLNode Right{ get; set; }
  public int Key{ get; set; }
  public int Height { get; set;}
}
```

And finally I want to get something like BaseNode and BaseTree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is `Link`? If you have a base class `Base` with `A : Base` and `B : Base`, do you need to know that `a.Link` is of type `A` and `b.Link` is of type `B`?

If not, it is as easy as:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Base Link { get; set; }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you need to preserve the type of `Link`, then what about generics?

```
public class Common<T>
{
    public T Link { get; set; }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var number = new Common<int>
    {
        Link = 27,
    };

    var text = new Common<string>
    {
        Link = "Hello World",
    };

    // This is impossible, because of the mismatch between types.
    ////var wrong = new Common<float>
    ////{
    ////    Link = "I'm not a float.",
    ////};

    Console.WriteLine(number.Link);
    Console.WriteLine(text.Link);   
}
```

**1. Refactoring: local method**

Specifying both the generic type and the link is annoying, especially if you have to change the types a lot. In some cases, you may even mistakenly specify the wrong type: either a parent class or a class which supports implicit type conversion, resulting in difficult to find bugs.

To avoid this, you can create a method which initializes a new instance of the `Common<T>` class based on the link:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var number = CreateCommon(27);
    var text = CreateCommon("Hello World");

    Console.WriteLine(number.Link);
    Console.WriteLine(text.Link);
}

private static Common<T> CreateCommon<T>(T link)
{
    return new Common<T>
    {
        Link = link,
    };
}

public class Common<T>
{
    public T Link { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Refactoring: factory pattern**

The first refactoring is enough if you use the `Common` class in one method. If you're using it in several classes, then you'll end up duplicating code (i.e. copy-pasting the `CreateCommon` method), or refactoring the previous piece of code into a one which uses a factory:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var number = Common.Factory.Create(27);
    var text = Common.Factory.Create("Hello World");

    Console.WriteLine(number.Link);
    Console.WriteLine(text.Link);
}

public class Common<T> : Common
{
    public Common()
    {
        // Do something here.
    }

    public Common(T link)
        : this()
    {
        this.Link = link;
    }

    public T Link { get; set; }
}

public class Common
{
    public static CommonFactory Factory
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommonFactory();
        }
    }
}

public class CommonFactory
{
    public Common<T> Create<T>(T link)
    {
        return new Common<T>(link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I updated my question. How can I use your answers for my situation?

Comment: @mif: `BSTree` and `AVLTree` can inherit from `Tree<TNode> where TNode : Node`; `BSTNode` and `AVLNode` — from `Node`. This way, you have a link between the types of trees and the corresponding types of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Wrapper {
    private A theA;
    private B theB;
    // these are private on purpose.

    // add properties and methods for A and B stuff that you
    // want to expose. Make sure the names look like they're
    // all from one coherent class.
    // make them `protected` as needed for use by only the subclasses.

    // do not give a default constructor so you force subclasses
    // to build correctly
    public Wrapper (A a, B b) {
        // check for null!

        theA = a;
        theB = b;
    }
}
```